# jupyter notebook is not importing beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

every other library is imported easily except beautifulsoup4 , I have already reinstall it several times.
python 3 i am using.

[image: **list of library install**]

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment so you have to activate the both virtual environment and jupyter notebook.

Comment: not using virtual env

Comment: Do you happen to have any other file named "bs4.py" in your path or workspace?

Comment: no i don't have any